# Is my company donating money to charity in lieu of paying me salary legal?

Tags: united-states, tax-law, corporate-tax-laws

I currently donate most of my money to charity, and knowing this my company has offered that they could deduce my salary and instead pay that money directly to charity.

I posted a [question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/146088/would-allowing-my-company-to-pay-me-less-in-order-to-donate-that-money-to-charit) to the finances board asking rather this would be a net gain to charity, and almost immediately someone suggested that this may constitute tax evasion and be illegal.  I wouldn't think my company would screw up by accidentally offering to do something that was illegal.

So would allowing my company to donate money to a charity I choose in lieu of a salary increase be legal for me and my company.

Comment: Would the deduction be pre-tax or post-tax?  If post-tax, no problem (but also no benefit to you).  Sources like https://finance.zacks.com/charitable-payroll-deductions-allowed-pretax-11182.html suggest that pre-tax charitable deductions are not allowed.

Comment: @NateEldredge pretax I believe.

Comment: And if the donations are entirely in the company's name, and don't appear as your salary at all, that may cause practical problems for you, independent of legality.  Suppose you were making $100K, and switch it to $40K plus a $60K donation.  In a couple years, you may want to look for a new job.  It'll be harder to convince a new employer that you are worth $100K+ in compensation when, on paper, you were only making $40K at your last job.

Comment: What happens if next year the company decides to stop making this charitable donation? Also what happens if they publicly claim this donation as their own in their PR?

Comment: @PaulJohnson personally I'm completely fine with them claiming the donations on their PR.  So long as the most money goes where it will do the most good I don't much care who gets credit, I mean it's a little dishonest of them and so I'd prefer they be honest, but it's not a big deal to me.  As to the later *if* i realize they do it I go to them and threaten to quit.  I'm luckily in a position where finding a new job is easy and have the leverage, they offered me this salary to not quite already it's unlikely they would refuse to give the salary back later.

Comment: @PaulJohnson Though I admit I do have a concern of rather I will know if my company is actually donating the money or not.  If they just told me they were donating it and I took their word for it I don't really have a good way to realize they stopped doing it.  A contract making them legally required to do it would help there, but may also push a legally grey situation into flat out illegal?  I trust my company, but that's allot of money to just entrust to others honesty.  Still how to handle proof of donations  is getting off topic, for now I'm just trying to figure out if it's even legal.

Comment: IANAL but I believe as long as your company pays you at least minimum wage then this should be OK.  But to be sure is your charity a real charity or a "Trump" charity?  If your charity buys goods and services for your comfort (or hoards money for possibly doing the same at a later date) then it is not a real charity and this is a tax scam.

Comment: There is a vital difference between "we pay you, and by your instructions your salary is deposited at the charity account" and "we do not pay you and we give the same amount to the charity". The later certainly has some legal risks (mainly for the company).

Answer (score 3):

The company pays you a salary A. They need to withhold some amount B of that to give to the IRS.

Now, if they pay you only C and withhold amount D that is based on that amount, and then make a separate tax-deductible donation E, that means the IRS does get not only an amount D that is smaller than B, but also the company can deduct E (in part) from their own taxes. As a result, that sounds like tax evasion on the face.

However, if they still pay you A, withhold B (the tax on the whole amount), and payout C to you as well as the donation as part of your salary, that could possibly be a legal way - though you might want to consult your tax consultant.

Comment: this would also be skirting employment taxes the employer bears.

Answer (score 0):

If your company wants to give money to charity, that is completely legal and not tax evasion.

Let's simplify this. The company offers you a salary increase, which you  decline. The company then donates the same amount of money to charity. In accounting terms, these are completely separate transactions. You are directly involved in the former, but are not directly involved in the latter.

At best, you are simply an advisor on the amount and recipient of the company's charitable donation. As long as the company gives the money directly to the charity, you are otherwise not involved.

Comment: But those are not unrelated transactions - there is an obvious quid pro quo.

Comment: Obvious? Really? The employee gets nothing. The company gets a charitable deduction. A third party gets most of the benefit. Unless the employee has some kind of stake in the charity, I fail to see the quid pro quo.

Comment: @Mohair if my desire is to have money go to charity then I have gotten the thing I desire have I not?  That seems like a benefit to me, even if my benefit also helps a third party.

Comment: @dsollen Your situation is no different than any employee (or non-employee) asking the company to donate funds to a charity. You can do it. Anyone can do it. The company can say yes or no. That the company does what you desire is wonderful, but your desire is not quantifiable and is not measured by any accounting system.

Comment: @Mohair but if it's done that way does that mean I have no way to ensure it happens.  Ie my company could stop donating the money next month and leave me at the lower salary?  If I ask for a means to ensure the company donates the money, which I would want to do if I give up so much, does that not switch it to a direct quid pro quo?

Comment: @dsollen If you want to formally structure it and monitor it monthly, then that certainly changes things. That would form the direct connection between the transactions that everyone involved should desperately want to avoid. The only way it makes sense to do this is for the company to make a lump sum, one-time donation to the charity.

Comment: @Mohair so what if I 'ask' my company to donate money each month at a set amount, then I call up the charity in question and politely request they inform me if they don't receive donations on any given month, with the understanding i'll be showing up to politely 'request' my company either start donating again or raise my salary back to what it was.  Then there isn't a formal structure with my company technically...but that still feels a whole lot like a quid pro quo situation to me.

Comment: @dsollen If you want the quid pro quo, then make it a quid pro quo. Write it up in a contract and enforce it. I don't see any other way you could make this arrangement work if you believe the company could or would stop sending the money. But I also don't see why the company would renege on the deal. Pay the charity or pay you the same amount, which is the better outcome for the company? Answer: pay the charity. The only complication is if the charity turns out to be fraudulent or supports some wildly controversial thing. But the company would just ask you to find something else, right?

Comment: @Mohair: The employee gets the satisfaction of having money given to their preferred charity, saving them the expense of giving their own money.  The company gets the continued services of the employee at a lower salary.  Clearly each of those is obtained in exchange for the other - if either one were to be withdrawn, the other would be too.

Comment: I don't know how to equate "reducing my salary" with "saving the expense of donating money to charity." Only if the employee were obligated to "donate" money to charity would that make sense. Also, the exchange is dubious. The net effect on either side is the same. Lower salary + charitable donation = X. Higher salary without charitable donation = X. The company likely benefits from the tax deduction with the donation, but there is no measurable benefit to the employee. The perceived happiness of an employee is not a financial instrument that is taxable.

Comment: @Mohair The tax needs to be equal in both cases though - you can **not** deduct charitable deductions pre-tax.